# testing if a value == NaT

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

converted a pandas column to datetime and I am left with some NaT values.  If the value is NaT I want to turn it into a specific date.

```
df['column'].iloc[122].isnull()

df['column'].iloc[122].isnull(pd.NaT)
```

tried it both ways where it am left with this error:
AttributeError: 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'isnull'

I just want to be able to loop through my column and have it perform like this:

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    if (df['column'].iloc[i] == NaT):
          df['column'].iloc[i] = datetime(2000, 1, 1)
```

thank you

Comment: Did you want `pd.isna(df['column'].iloc[122])`?

Comment: yes, and that worked!  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):

   if pd.isnull(df['column'].iloc[i]):
```

Comment: @Raz How is this a link-only answer?